# Way to get Microsoft Word to remember "Find and Replace" entries for auto complete the next time after closing Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, find, find-and-replace

After you use “find what”, or “replace with”, the entry will be remembered for auto complete the next time.

When you quit Microsoft Word, the suggestions are no longer remembered.

Is there a way to get Word to remember "Find and Replace" (Ctrl-H) entries
from one session to the next?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this tool (Word VBA addon): [VBA Find & Replace](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html)

This tool lets you use a custom replacement list of word pairs in Word or Excel format to process either a single document or batch process multiple Word documents.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried Recording the action as a [macro:](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/UsingRecorder.htm)